# How to wait until function returns a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
  let isTokenActive = this.checkIfRefreshTokenWorking(refresh_token);
}

checkIfRefreshTokenWorking = (refresh_token) => {
  let trueOrFalse = false;
  fetch('http://localhost:8888/refresh_token?refresh_token='+refresh_token)
   .then(response => {
     response.json()
     trueOrFalse = true;
   })
   .catch(err => {
     trueOrFalse = false;
   })
   .finally(() => {      
     return trueOrFalse;
   })
}
```

`isTokenActive` gets undefined. I want to wait until `checkIfRefreshTokenWorking` returns a value. Do I need to create a promise for this?

Comment: you need a promise for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Javascript Promises

The function passed to new Promise is called the executor. When new Promise is created, the executor runs automatically. It contains the producing code which should eventually produce the result. In terms of the analogy above: the executor is the “singer”.

Its arguments resolve and reject are callbacks provided by JavaScript itself. Our code is only inside the executor.

> **This is not tested code**

```
componentDidMount() {
        let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        this.checkIfRefreshTokenWorking(refresh_token)
              .then((data) => console.log(data))
              .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

checkIfRefreshTokenWorking = (refresh_token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     let trueOrFalse = false;
        fetch('http://localhost:8888/refresh_token?refresh_token='+refresh_token)
        .then(response => {
          response.json()
          trueOrFalse = true;
          resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch(err => {
          trueOrFalse = false;
          reject(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {      
            return trueOrFalse;
            resolve();
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. Using `async/await` with refresh token call
2. Make use of `conditional rendering` way

```
// You need to use babel present env for this
async componentDidMount() {
  const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  let isTokenActive = false;
  try {
    const response = awit fetch('http://localhost:8888/refresh_token?refresh_token=' + refresh_token);
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data);
    isTokenActive = true;
  } catch(err) {
    // Log the error
  }
} 

// Conditional rendering
this.state = {
  ...,
  isLoading: false,
  isTokenActive: false
};

componentDidMount() {
  const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  fetch('http://localhost:8888/refresh_token?refresh_token=' + refresh_token)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
    .finally(...); // Set the value for isLoading/isTokenActive with this.setState accordingly
}

render() {
  const { isLoading, isTokenActive } = this.state;
  !isLoading ? isTokenActive ? <MyComponent /> : <div /> : <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

References:

- https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react
- https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @oldBear, Note: I am not using seperate `checkIfRefreshTokenWorking` function here. You can write it in a separate function and wrap it with promise as per `Ferin Patel's` answer if you want.

Comment: My problem was more about not being able to access to value but thanks much.